# News and Weather API

Tags: api, rss, xmlreader, feed, weather-api

Is their a way to implement either sky.com, bt.com or bbc.com's weather and/or news API into our website ?

If so can you please explain how to do this and its not going to be used to make money its purpose is to allow our visitors to see the latest weather and news updates

Our site can support basic html shtml htm etc and .jsp .php 5.3 and mysql

Thanks for any help/advice in advance

I have already tried various other apis like Yahoo! Weather but i cant get it to work because i need it to locate the user and display weather for their current location like the BBC, Sky and BT does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metwit [weather API](http://metwit.com/developers/),
You can implement them client-side: 200 request/day (ip based throttling) no authentication required. Worldwide coverage, JSON and REST compliant.
You can register for extra API calls for free and if you still need it to call them server side the basic plan is pretty cheap.

Full disclosure: I own this sweet piece of API.